# Careers sample profile went missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In the [Get a Stack Overflow Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one) page (note: must be logged out of Careers to see the page, otherwise you'll reach your own profile) there is a link [See a sample profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/maxhorstmann):

> [image]

However, as you can see it's leading to a 404 error page. No sample for us. Can the user please be called back to arms, or replaced with someone less evasive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sample profiles we simply find a profile that has the following properties:

- public
- belongs to a developer
- has a route associated with it

Alas Max's profile is no longer public and the fact that it is still trying to show it is possibly down to caching. When I visit the page I now see [Nick's profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/nicklarsen) - can you verify you see the same?

UPDATE: Turns out this was slightly inconsistent across the code base; in the case above we didn't filter for profiles that are public. I've pushed a change that makes sure we use the same mechanism for finding sample profiles everywhere! That should sort it. Thanks for finding :)

Comment: Cheers, but I think something is burning... :D